# Units of noise spectral density

Tags: dac, noise-spectral-density, units

I'm reading the [datasheet of a DAC](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD5762R.pdf) (see page 6), and the "Output Noise Spectral Density" has units `V / Hz^(1/2)`.

The [Wikipedia article on noise spectral density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_spectral_density) however states that the noise spectral density has unit `Watt / Hz`.

Those two units are not equivalent. Why is there a discrepancy in the units?

Comment: see also [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32257/noise-and-what-does-v-hz-actually-mean). (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The \$\mathrm{W/Hz}\$ may be a bit confusing as it looks like it refers to a single frequency. But that's just the dimension, it actually refers to a bandwidth, which is also expressed in Hz: maximum frequency - minimum frequency. So it's the power over a given bandwidth.

If you divide power by the load's resistance you get voltage squared. So **for a given load** you can express noise power as

\$ \mathrm{\dfrac{V^2}{BW}}\$

where \$\mathrm{BW}\$ is bandwidth. If you want to know the voltage you take the square root:

\$ \mathrm{\sqrt{\dfrac{V^2}{BW}} = \dfrac{V}{\sqrt{BW}}}\$

which indeed has the dimension of \$\mathrm{V/\sqrt{Hz}}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Both units show you the same thing, just in a slightly different form. From the perspective of a DAC, the noise voltage is what matters since the DAC is outputting specific voltages. However, in a communication system, the noise power is what matters, so in that case people prefer to use Watts.

Also remember that Watts and Volts are related by a square. P=V^2/R, we can ignore the R here since its just a scaling factor. So inversely if you take the square-root of Watts you will end up with volts.

Comment: Ok, so that explains that `Watt` versus `Volts` discrepancy. What about the square root?